# How to check if a model exists in a list of another model in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose `User` model, and a mongoose `Conversation` model.
The `Conversation` model has a participants field containing an `Array` of `Users`.

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        min: 5, max: 35,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 8
    }
},
    { timestamps: true }
)

const ConversationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    participants: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
        validate: (participants) => participants.length > 0
    }
},
    { timestamps: true }
)
```

How do I find all conversations having a specific user as participant using `mongoose.model.find()`?

Comment: Can you specify (as text) your schema for Conversation and User?

Answer (score 0):

Just search as below. If there is the user id you specified in the array, all results will be returned.

```
const Conversation = mongoose.model("Conversation");

const conversations = await Conversation.find({
    user: user_id
  })
```